# Use axios request insde a for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, axios

I'm beginner in js. I'm using vuejs, axios and this api https://www.balldontlie.io to work on a homework project. This project must be to consult nba players stats. I need your help to solve problems. Here is my code :

```
var app = new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    teams: null,
    players: [],
    selectedTeam: null,
    selectedTeamPlayers: [],
    selection: false,
    id : [],
    season_averages : []
  },
  methods: {
    getAllPlayers() {
      axios.get('https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=100').then(response => {
        let total = response.data.meta.total_pages;
        let req = [];
        let url = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=100&page=';
        for (let i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
          req.push(axios.get(url + i));
        }

        axios.all(req).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
            let jsonPlayers = responses[i].data.data;

            for (let j = 0; j < jsonPlayers.length; j++) {
              this.players.push(jsonPlayers[j]);
              this.id.push(jsonPlayers[j].id);
            }
          }
          console.log(this.id);
        }));

      });

    },
    getSeasons() {
      let seasons = getAllplayers(); 
      let sa = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < seasons; i++) {
            axios.get("https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/season_averages?player_ids[]=" + i).then(response => {
            sa[i] = response.data.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < sa.length; i++) {
                this.season_averages.push(sa[i]);
            }

      });   
    }

      console.log(season_averages);
    }

  },
  mounted() {
    this.getSeasons();
    this.getAllPlayers();

  }
});
```

So I'm making request to get data of nba players and teams. In this script, my first function returns a json structure containing only the id of the players. The second one is supposed to return saisons averages of all the players. However, you can only access the stats of a specific players.
I mean, you can access the stats players in function of his id passed in parameter of the url.

Example : https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/season_averages?player_ids[]=237
This url display the saisons averages of the player having the id equal to 237.

So what I want to do is to get all of them and to do that I have to get the ID of all the players. This is why I need the first function. I'm gonna use it in the second function to concate each id with the url of the api to. So I can access and store all of them into an array and return all there stats.

My question is how can I use for loop on axios request to get seasons avergages of each players ?

Regards

YT

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` for this issue. 
Let’s say we have an array of fruits we want to get from the fruit basket.

```
const fruitsToGet = ['apple', 'grape', 'pear']
```

We simply create a function that returns a specific fruit after some time:

```
const sleep = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

const getNumFruit = fruit => {
  return sleep(1000).then(v => fruitBasket[fruit])
}
```

We are going to loop through this array.

```
const forLoop = async _ => {
  console.log('Start')

  for (let index = 0; index < fruitsToGet.length; index++) {
    // Get num of each fruit
  }

  console.log('End')
}
```

In the for-loop, we will use `getNumFruit` to get the number of each fruit. We’ll also log the number into the console.

Since `getNumFruit` returns a promise, we can await the resolved value before logging it.

```
const forLoop = async _ => {
  console.log('Start')

  for (let index = 0; index < fruitsToGet.length; index++) {
    const fruit = fruitsToGet[index]
    const numFruit = await getNumFruit(fruit)
    console.log(numFruit)
  }

  console.log('End')
}
```

When you use await, you expect JavaScript to pause execution until the awaited promise gets resolved. This means awaits in a for-loop should get executed in series.

The result is what you’d expect

This behaviour works with most loops (like while and for-of loops)…

But it won’t work with loops that require a callback. Examples of such loops that require a fallback include forEach, map, filter, and reduce. We’ll look at how await affects forEach, map, and filter in the next few sections.
[Source](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/)

Comment: Thank you for answering but I dont really see how can I implement that with my code. Could you be more precise please ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see - you are writing asynchronous code and expecting synchronous execution. When you homework is to include these two functions - then they both should return Promises.

If you just want to stick some stats to a player - a simpler approach could work, too.

```
const playerurl = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search=LeBron';
const statsurl =
  'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/season_averages?player_ids[]=';

axios.get(playerurl).then(playerData => {
  const statsPromises = playerData.data.data.map(function(player) { // Use Array.map to create promises
    return axios.get(statsurl + player.id).then(function(result) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) { // Chain promises
        player.stats = result.data.data;
        resolve(player); // Finally resolve the player and stats
      });
    });
  });

  Promise.all(statsPromises).then(function(playerStats) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(playerStats));
  });
});
```

```
[
  {
    "id": 237,
    "first_name": "LeBron",
    "height_feet": 6,
    "height_inches": 8,
    "last_name": "James",
    "position": "F",
    "team": {
      "id": 14,
      "abbreviation": "LAL",
      "city": "Los Angeles",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Pacific",
      "full_name": "Los Angeles Lakers",
      "name": "Lakers"
    },
    "weight_pounds": 250,
    "stats": [
      {
        "games_played": 52,
        "player_id": 237,
        "season": 2019,
        "min": "34:53",
        "fgm": 9.58,
        "fga": 19.52,
        "fg3m": 2.12,
        "fg3a": 6.15,
        "ftm": 3.85,
        "fta": 5.52,
        "oreb": 0.96,
        "dreb": 6.75,
        "reb": 7.71,
        "ast": 10.73,
        "stl": 1.27,
        "blk": 0.46,
        "turnover": 3.98,
        "pf": 1.71,
        "pts": 25.12,
        "fg_pct": 0.491,
        "fg3_pct": 0.344,
        "ft_pct": 0.697
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Maybe there is more to be done - that's where you and homework come in!

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wante but with all the players